# Redirecting a modal form to my php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to redirect my modal form to my php script, I've used action but for some reason the button just clicks and stops.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" role="form" target="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
  </div>

  <!-- Form submit button -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="action.php" data-toggle="button" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</div> <!-- opened somewhere else -->
</div> <!-- opened somewhere else -->

<p>
  <!-- Opens the modal -->
  <button class="btn btn-light" data-target="#surveymodal" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Submit</button>

  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: **cough** `type="button"` is not right **cough**

Comment: I tried to improve code readability, event hough the question is still unclear to me. Does the modal open? Is the form inside the modal? Are you getting any error in your devtools console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button's type seems to be incorrect:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-light" data-target="#surveymodal" data-toggle="modal" type="submit">Submit</button><script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script><script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></p>
```

Fix above.